# Tweet button in Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, ui-design

Is it against any iOS Interface guidelines to have a custom button in the Navigation Bar? I have a tweet button with a twitter icon on the right of the navigation bar. Just wanted to confirm. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm fairly certain no style guide I've ever read says, "Don't put a custom tweet button in the Navigation bar."  But UINavigationBar and related support custom buttons, so it would be silly for the style guide to ban them.  I've seen all sorts of apps with all sorts of customization going on up there—some good, some bad.

If your button is well designed and looks like a button, has a clear twitter-y icon, and is something you expect your users to do fairly frequently, I think you'll fall well within acceptable use.  You should do some usability testing and verify.